# What is the electric field strength required to rip apart particles

Tags: electromagnetism, electric-fields, water

Water is a polar molecule, one side slightly positive and the other slightly negative. Would it be possible to rip a water molecule apart into hydrogen and oxygen gas using charged parallel plates with a very intense electric field? If so, what would the electric field strength need to be? Also what voltage would be required? I know the distance between the plates is another factor, so whatever makes this work for distance is good.

My guess is the negative plate would attract the hydrogen ions and the positive plate would attract the oxygen ions.

I feel like I am missing a key understanding or concept here why this won't work. Any clarity in this regard would be great.

Comment: Are you asking about https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electrolysis ?  Or about https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breakdown_voltage ?

Comment: Even 'breakdown' generally means ripping an electron off the molecule. Once into avalanche breakdown of the gas, well, your voltage tend to collapse quite quickly.